# Is a 2D array of C++ vectors suitable for keeping track of a 2D array's dynamic domain values?

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, oop, vector

Writing a C++ [backtracking with CSP algorithm](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hojjat/384w09/Lectures/Lecture-04-Backtracking-Search.pdf) program, to [solve a Sudoku puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku).

Variables are mapped to a 9X9 grid (81 variables), [so the program is row/column oriented](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-7-suduku/).

To make backtracking smarter, the program needs to keep track of the possible values that each variable on the 9X9 grid can still accept.

(The list of numbers is 1 - 9 for each of the 81 variables and is constantly changing.)

My initial thought is to use a **2D array of** vectors - to map to each variable.

For example vector[1][5] will contain all the possible values for variable[1][5].

In terms of efficiency and ease of use - is this the right container or is there something else that works better?

Comment: Using a vector sounds overkill for this task. If you're only after numbers 1-9, why don't you use `vector[1][5]` as a bitmap? In other words, make `vector` a 2D array of ints and use each position as a bitmap to keep track of what numbers you have tried / need to try.

Comment: @filipe-goncalves: ok that sounds like an effective method, so if I wanted to remove 5 from a variables domain, I would AND it's domain value with the int value equal to 111101111 ?

Comment: See my answer, I show a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `std::vector` for this sounds unnecessary and overkill. Since you know the exact domain of your variables, and it's only the numbers 1-9, I suggest using a two dimensional array where each position works as a bitmap.

Code sample (untested):

```
short vector[9][9] = { 0 };

/* v must be in the range [1-9] */

void remove_value(int x, int y, int v) {
    vec[x][y] |= 1 << v;
}

int test_value(int x, int y, int v) {
    return (vec[x][y] & (1 << v));
}

int next_value(int x, int y) {
    int res = 1;
    for (int mask = 2; 
         mask != (1 << 10) && (vector[x][y] & mask); 
         mask <<= 1, res++)
         ; /* Intentionally left blank */
    return res;
}
```

Think of `vector[x][y]` as a binary integer initialized to 0:

`...0000000000`

The meaning is such that a bit `i` set to 1 means you have already tested number `i`, otherwise, you haven't tested it yet. Bit counting, as usual, is right to left, and starts from 0. You will only be using bits 1 to 9.

`remove_value()` should be called everytime you finished testing a new value (that is, to remove this value from the domain), and `test_value()` can be used to check if `v` has ever been tested - it will return 0 if `v` has not been used yet, and something that is not 0 otherwise (to be precise, `1 << v`). `next_value()` will give you the next value to test for a position [x,y] sorted in ascending order, or 10 if every value in the range 1-9 has already been tested.